# single installation experience for application and bootstrapper in wix

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

hii,
i made a bootstrapper for my msi to check and install the prerequisites..and when i click the 
setup.exe file it smoothly check and install..there is no problem in it..

*)For now i use GenerateBootstrapper and bootstrapperFile to create bootstrapper.

But my problem is this that when the prerequisite are installed they use there own install window.but i want to provide single installation feel..
i want to run every prerequisite file in my own customized UI ..
i want to customize the Ui of them.How can i do this?? can anyone help me out??

thanks.

Comment: Which prerequisites? How are they installed MSI? Exe's?

Comment: prerequisites like windows installer 3.1,sql server,ms framework 2.0 etc. i want them to b installed in my system before installing my application.these are all done through bootstrapper(setup.exe) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as I can tell currently there is no way of doing it with wix only.

Butwix3.5 should contain sth called Burn http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn

Comment: Or if you're running one of the bleeding-edge development weekly releases (http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/) you'll find BURN in there too.

Comment: Is there any other documentation of how to use BURN.exe except the above link??..

Comment: Burn was officially released as part of WiX v3.6. There is documentation in the WiX.chm, see the `Bundle` element and related topis.